# For $Ax=b$, why does x has to be linear combination of column space of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ has eigenvalues $0, 3, 5$ with independent eigenvectors $u, v, w$.

1. Find a particular solution to $Ax = v + w$.
2. Find all solutions.

the solution was given in the sense of $x$ is a linear combination of the column space of $A$.

How could that happend ?
I could not understand why ?

Comment: You mean $b$, instead of $x$, is in the column space of $A$?

Comment: @Azif00 Note that $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of $A$ with nonzero eigenvalues, so they, too, live in the column space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given that $Au=0(u)=0, Av=3v, Aw=5w$. Thus we have $A\left(\frac{v}{3}\right)=v$ and $A\left(\frac{w}{5}\right)=w$. Using the linearity, we get 
$$A\left(\frac{v}{3}\right)+A\left(\frac{w}{5}\right)=A\left(\frac{v}{3}+\frac{w}{5}\right)=v+w.$$
Thus $x=\frac{v}{3}+\frac{w}{5}$ is a particular solution.

Observe that $v,w$ are eigenvectors, therefore they are in column space of $A$ (because $Av=3v, Aw=5w$, so $v,w$ are ''good'' right hand sides.) Since column space is a subspace, **therefore the vector $x=\frac{v}{3}+\frac{w}{5}$ is also in the column space of $A$.**

Comment: How about $x=\frac v3+\frac w5+t\cdot u\,, t\in\Bbb F$ for the general solution?

Comment: @ChrisCuster Oops my error!!, fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $x$ is a column vector, it is a linear combination of basis vectors $I_n$ of the form $$I_n=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\\vdots\\1\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}$$But, note that $$A\cdot I_n=C_n$$where $C_n$ is the $n$th column of $A$. So, by linearity, the columns of $A$ span the space of possible $b$ in $Ax=b$.

Comment: Umm... that’s not what was asked, though. The OP is asking why the particular solution to $Ax=v+w$ must lie in the column space, and that has to do with $v$ and $w$ being eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

Expand the product $A\mathbf x$ in terms of the columns $\mathbf a_j$ of $A$: $$(A\mathbf x)_i = \sum_j a_{ij}x_j = \sum_j x_j\mathbf a_j.$$ That is, the product of a matrix and vector is a linear combination of the columns of the matrix with the coefficient the corresponding elements of the vector. So, for any vector $\mathbf x$ whatsoever, the product $A\mathbf x$ lies in the column space of $A$.

In particular, if $\mathbf x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $A\mathbf x$ must lie in the column space, but $A\mathbf x=\lambda\mathbf x$, so when $\lambda\ne0$, $\mathbf x$ itself must also be an element of $A$’s column space. Working backwards, if $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with nonzero eigenvalue $\lambda$, then one solution of $A\mathbf x=\mathbf v$ is $\mathbf x=\mathbf v/\lambda$. By linearity, then, one solution to $A\mathbf x=\mathbf v+\mathbf w$, with both $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$ eigenvectors with nonzero eigenvalues, is a linear combination of $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf w$, but since both eigenvectors live in the column space, it’s also some linear combination of the columns of $A$. That gives you a particular solution. To get all solutions, observe that the null space of $A$ is spanned by $\mathbf u$.